# use JQuery in Laravel Blade loop

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a question regarding JQuery and Laravel Blade

For example in My `index.blade.php`

```php
...

@for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
  <div id="something-{{$i}}" data-value="{{ $i }}"></div>
@endfor

<script>
  $( "#something-"+value ).data(value);

</script>
...
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to get the 'value' in the JQuery example above so that I can get the data for each of the html element. Can anyone point me where I can study the solution for this. This might not be a good example but I'm just trying to get the idea here.

I've edited the question to give a clearer view of what I want to achieve

Many Thanks :)

Comment: Did you mean you want the **value** of the button?

Comment: @lizeshakya This is just an example. I just want to get the idea on how use value from the loop on html element and call it using jquery. I just don't know how to get the value and use it in jquery. Sorry for my explanation. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: where the `value` come from?

Comment: @yovie that is exactly what I'm trying to figure out here. How can I get the value in the jquery so that it can match the id the html element and I can use the it many time.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake of quotation near id and to pass the value of same id I used the java script function and then accessed the value inside it.

```
@for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
<button id="something-{{ $i }}" onclick="doSomething({{ $i }})"></button>
@endfor

<script>
function doSomething(value) {
    $.( "#something-"+value ).click(function() {
        alert( "Hello" );
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you add some explanation please

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
  <button class="button-list" custom-value="{{ $i }}"></button>
@endfor

<script>
  $( ".button-list" ).click(function() {
    var custom_value = $(this).attr('custom-value');
    alert(custom_value);
  });
</script>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So two different things here.

Your "blade" code gets executed when the file is sent from the server to the user.

The jQuery code is executed and used on the user device directly.

Therefore there is not really any interactions between the two.

jQuery interacts with the html created by your blade template.

For example with what you've written you would end up with three buttons in an html file, and to use jQuery on those you would end up doing something like that
HTML :

```
<button id="something-1">BUTTON 1</button>
<button id="something-1">BUTTON 2</button>
<button id="something-1">BUTTON 3</button>
```

jQuery :

```
$('[id^="something-"]').click(function() {
    alert('Hello');
});
```

See it here : https://jsfiddle.net/8eLu71n3/1/

A better solution would be to have a class on your button and to bind your event on this class.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a data attribute in each  element, like data-id or data-number, with a commom id. Like this:

```
@for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
<button id="myButton" data-id={{ $i }}></button>
@endfor
```

Then in javascript, i would do this:

```
$("#myButton").each(function(button){
     button.click = function() {
        alert('hello');
     }
});
```

Comment: This will cause a problem since the same id will be implemented for three buttons.

Comment: But that is not a problem, you can use a class attribute if you want. The point here is that you can select all buttons in jQuery but yet have an attribute to know which button is.

Answer (score 0):

You have a **""** in your button blade. Remove one of the **""** near the something-

If you need to use the variable of the Laravel blade to jQuery/javascript, you can embed the value in the **data-** in the Laravel blade. You can use **data()** in your script file to retrieve the value.

```
@for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
<button id="something-"{{ $i }}" data-value="{{$i}}" class="something"></button> 
@endfor

// Using cdn jQuery version 3.4.1 
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

 $( ".something" ).click(function() {
   var value = $(this).data('value');
   alert( value + ' button is clicked' );
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the same function from any of the button using it's ID then you have to add event listener inside element as below:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
    <button id="something-"{{ $i }} onclick="doAlert(this.id);">Button {{$i}}</button>
@endfor
```

Now create doAlert() function inside your JS file:

```
function doAlert(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$('#something-' + value).click(function(){
     let ids = $(this).attr('id');
     let splitted = ids.split('-');
    if (splitted[1]) {
      alert('the value ' + splitted[1]);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    @for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
      <button class="something_class" button_value="{{$i}}" id="something-{{ $i }}"></button>
    @endfor

    <script>
      $( ".something_class" ).click(function() {
           let button_value = $(this).attr("button_value");
           alert( button_value  );
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me best way would be adding a class to button and use `$(this)` to refer current DOM object.

```
@for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
  <button id="something-{{ $i }}" class='button_click'></button>
@endfor

<script>
  $( ".button_click" ).click(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    alert( "Hello" );
  });
</script>
```